# Is there any difference for logging into a form where method=get and no name is set

Tags: python, forms, get, urllib2, urllib

I am trying to log into a form using either urllib2 or requests. When I look at any  [other examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685235/login-using-python-in-basic-html-form) they always have two key differences. The first is that their form always has

`<form method="POST">`

while the form I am trying to log into has no method set ([and therefore defaults to method="GET"](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3))

The second difference is that my form does not have any name attributes inside the input elements, only id attributes.

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949516/python-3-login-form-on-webpage-with-urllib-and-cookiejar) where a user said that urllib only sends name attributes.

Since none of the examples work, how would I go about logging into a form like this?

--Edit--

Upon [further research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837195/form-submission-in-python-without-name-attribute?rq=1) it seems that my form is most likely handled by java script not html. Are there any alternatives to selenium (which is painfully slow) that can login to this type of form form.

Comment: Use the browser's debugger and see what is actually send.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the `name` attribute is what matters for a HTML form.